# SQL COALESCE dealing with NULL + 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL of users that holds 2 fields:

ID (int) || Name (text)

when I insert a new user to the table, the table should set his ID as the next index in the ID list, i.e if the IDs in the list are: 1, 2, 3
the next user that will be added will be assigned with the ID = 4.

To do that, I'm getting the max ID value in the table and incrementing it, the problem is that if the table is empty, MAX function returns null, in order to deal with that - I decided to use COALESCE as follows:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES COALESCE(0,(SELECT MAX(id) FROM users) + 1), 'Smith');
```

Which intended to put 0 in case a NULL value is returned from MAX function.

Problem is that while `SELECT MAX(id) FROM USERS` does return a NULL value, when i add the  `+1` it gives an error.

How can that be fixed? I have the intention to keep it in one query.

Comment: It's `COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id) FROM users), 0) + 1`

Comment: Wouldn't that put 1 in case of an empty table? I want the IDs to start from 0.

Comment: Check @gordon's answer.

Comment: @jarlh the mysql tag is because COALESCE can be used in MySQL and I assume people who know mysql queries can help with this, as well as programmers that are looking for help with either postgre or mysql

Comment: Almost any dbms support coalesce (ANSI SQL function)... Don't tag products not directly involved!

Comment: What if a mysql (for example) programmer has the same prablem? should he open a new question just because he's using a different dbms? It would be harder for him to find that question, wouldn't it?

Comment: Do ***not*** generate new IDs using `select max()...`. It is not safe in a multi user environment (and if it is it's slow and will not scale). Use a sequence (or `serial`)  instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values are backwards (and you are missing parentheses in the `VALUES()`.  I think a simpler way of writing such a query is to use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO users(id, Name)
     SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id) + 1, 0), 'Smith'
     FROM users;
```

Note:  you should list all the columns when doing an insert.  It will prevent hard-to-find errors when you use SQL.

However, the right way to do this is by defining `id` as `serial`, which are described [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).  Then, the database maintains the id column.

Comment: that doesn't help much because I want the IDs to start from 0.

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer . . . I just saw that comment and fixed the code.  Normally, such ids start from 1 rather than 0; there is no particular reason why but that is how sequences, identities, auto increment values, and serial works in various databases by default (all can be overridden to start at 0).

Comment: Thanks. my mistake was the order of the parameters in the COALESCE function?

Answer (score 0):

Swap the order of appearance;

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES (COALESCE(SELECT MAX(id) FROM users, -1) + 1), 'Smith');
```